CSS :checked property for use without javascript - the clickable functionality still after click - revert to unchecked so it can be used again
Am having issues with getting scroll functionality working properly using CSS only with hidden input boxes using checked property. It seems to work as expected on first load of page - click right and left arrow and works perfect, but when the right arrow is clicked again the action seems to have been removed - I guess as the input item has been set to checked so that may be an issue as the status is changed (I thought there might be a way to keep the functionality after the first click) maybe using not(:checked) is an option or it can be reset to default using CSS workaround?
I'm just trying to explore if there's any way to keep what I have using CSS only without the use of Javascript.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Scroll wrapper with hidden overflow */

.scroll-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  /* Fixed width for the wrapper */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide default scrollbar */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Center the wrapper horizontally */
}


/* Scrollable container with scroll behavior */

.scroll-container {
  display: flex;
  /* Arrange items horizontally */
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /* Same width as the wrapper */
  width: 1400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* Allow horizontal scroll */
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  /* Snapping effect */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  /* Smooth scroll */
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  /* Small animation movement */
}


/* Style for each scroll item */

.scroll-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
  /* Fixed width for images */
  height: 350px;
  /* Fixed height for images */
  margin-right: 10px;
  /* Space between items */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  /* Snap to the start of each item */
}

.scroll-item img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Make the image fill the scroll item */
  height: 100%;
  /* Ensure the image maintains the container's size */
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Ensure the image covers the area */
}

.scroll-item:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* Hide the scrollbar in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) */

.scroll-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


/* Style for the hidden checkboxes used for interaction */

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}


/* Arrows (using labels for styling) */

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.arrow-left {
  left: 10px;
}

.arrow-right {
  right: 10px;
}


/* Show arrows when container is hovered */

.scroll-wrapper:hover .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Movement of the scroll container when arrows are clicked */

#scrollRight[type="checkbox"]:checked~.scroll-container {
  /*transform: translateX(-350px);*/
  /* Move container to the left when checkbox is checked */
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}


/* Movement of the scroll container when arrows are clicked */

#scrollLeft[type="checkbox"]:checked~.scroll-container {
  /*transform: translateX(-350px);*/
  /* Move container to the left when checkbox is checked */
  transform: translateX(0px);
}


/* Arrows via labels (styled as buttons) */

label.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.arrow-left {
  left: 5px;
}

label.arrow-right {
  right: 5px;
}


/* New styling to prevent whitespace after sliding */

.scroll-wrapper input:checked~.scroll-container {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Horizontal Scroll with CSS Arrows and Smooth Transition</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="scroll-wrapper">
    <!-- Hidden checkboxes to trigger scroll actions -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="scrollLeft">
    <input type="checkbox" id="scrollRight">

    <!-- Labels acting as arrows -->
    <label for="scrollLeft" class="arrow arrow-left">←</label>
    <label for="scrollRight" class="arrow arrow-right">→</label>

    <!-- Scrollable content -->
    <div class="scroll-container">
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350" alt="Image 1">
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350" alt="Image 2">
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350" alt="Image 3">
      </div>
      <div class="scroll-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/350" alt="Image 4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




I answered a very similar question back in 2020 - see my solution here - and also here.

Try using radio buttons like <input type="radio" name="direction"> sharing the same name. Therefore when one is checked, another would be automatically unchecked. no JS.
